# Boost - warning about dereferencing pointers when building

Tags: c++, boost, strict-aliasing

I'm following the "Getting started" [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) from the Boost website. I'm trying to build separatly-compiled libraries using the following commands:

```
./bootstrap.sh
```

and then

```
./b2
```

During the building, I'm getting a lot (like hundreds) of those warnings:

```
./boost/...whatever.hpp:linenumber: warning: dereferencing pointer ‘...’ does break strict-aliasing rules
```

I'd like to know if it is a problem on my side and if I can do something to get rid of these warnings?

Thanks.

(Boost 1.48, Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cellperformance](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) states that strict aliasing is:

> [...] an assumption, made by the C (or C++) compiler,
>   that dereferencing pointers to objects of different types will never
>   refer to the same memory location (i.e. alias eachother.)

This warning occurs when `-fno-strict-aliasing` and optimizations (`-O2` or higher) are enabled because the compiler needs to be much more conservative when its accessing (possibly) aliased memory. This leads to less optimizations - the compiler can't e.g. really be sure that elements doesn't overlap (see example in article posted above).

This is not a warning you should worry about - the Boost developers are probably aware of this and have good reasons to why this is ok.

Comment: This _is_ something to worry about if it's encountered in new code, though!

Comment: @xtofl: Indeed. All warnings are.

Comment: "_the Boost developers are probably aware of this_" Did you ask them?

Comment: @curiousguy: No, if I did I could remove the _probably_ ;)